# Call to undefined function password_hash() PHP 5.3.19

Tags: php

Hi I am try to use the `password_hash()` function like so

```
echo password_hash("mySecretPassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

But I am gettig this error which I can figure out

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()
```

My current PHP version is 5.3.19 32 bit

What is the cause of this issue?

Comment: [Per the docs, `password_hash()` is PHP 5.5+](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: See https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: Someone didn't bother reading the manual fully (*or at all*). For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: The highly voted answers to question lay out your options expertly. [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Comment: fully? i would bet a dollar for *at all*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be answered by simply reading the manual

Comment: I stand *corrected* @Dagon

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/password_hash).

> password_hash()
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)

This means that only version after 5.5.0 has this method implemented. Running 5.3.0 will not work. There is however a fallback option posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/921563).

You could also use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: 1 second reading the manual would of answered this

Comment: Indeed it would. Guessing this will be closed rather quickly, but now there is an answer for people roaming the interwebs later. This is not the last time this question will be asked ;)